# Javascript not supported error in jsoup

Tags: javascript, android, selenium, jsoup

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BjQk.jpg)http://www.biletix.com/search/TURKIYE/en#!city_sb:İstanbul,date_sb:today

i want to get element from this link. But output console shows javascript not found, please enable it and then closes.

I will migrate this project to android. Jsoup is good to migrate but what about selenium?

[Selenium into android project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33138134/selenium-into-android-project)

Here he couldnot migrate to studio. And is there anyway to get this page? I want to take element with id `all_result`

[[image: here you can see, i want to extract name, date and venue.]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inspected the page you are trying to scrape, found out that the information you desire is retrieved with `JavaScript` in the form of `JSON`. So I went ahead and discovered a url you can use to retrieve that `JSON` data:  http://www.biletix.com/solr/en/select/?start=0&rows=100&fq=end%3A%5B2015-11-21T00%3A00%3A00Z%20TO%202015-11-21T00%3A00%3A00Z%2B1DAY%5D&sort=vote%20desc,start%20asc&&fq=city:%22%C4%B0stanbul%22&wt=json&json.wrf=jsonp1448055842231

You might wanna consider using getting contents of this url to work with!

Comment: thank you but i couldnot see the elements i want to parse. iadded a picture.

Comment: please help.how can i do this, get this link?